# An Error Occurred during Save the drawing in Autocad

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I have try to save drawing using ActiveDocument.save(). But i received Warning message some thing like "warning an error occurred during save we recommend that you run recover". Can anybody help me how to solve this.

[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: we need more data, for instance, if you have vertical objects (ACA, C3D, etc) and where is being saved. Also, have you wblock it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because the drawing is open, therefore cannot be saved...

Can you try call CloseInput(true)?

Comment: He / she could also have corrupted the Database; one cannot really say without seeing the rest of the code.